# undo scaffold before rollback ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I only realised I had to `rails db:rollback` after I destroyed scaffold. Is there any way I could delete a table now?

I created a table called reviews then destroyed the scaffold but still have table reviews in my schema.rb which I want to get rid of.

is there a solution for this please?

Comment: You can re-generate the scaffold, then do the rollback. Be careful of course.

Comment: So would I ```rails g scaffold reviews``` with all the attributes I already did? Won't that give an error to say it already exists?

Comment: I thought you said you had already destroyed the scaffold. Also, it doesn't really matter what attributes you provide to the scaffold, all you're trying to run is a `drop table` anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can drop that table with `rails console`

in `console`

`ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table :reviews`

then in `terminal`

`rake db:schema:dump`

to update schema file